# Checkboxset element in form - not posting values of Field

Tags: uicomponent, adminform

I have begun creating a custom form for magento, this form include the elemenet checkboxset as documented here... https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-checkboxset.html

My form also includes other Fields.

In my controller I get the value of the fields using $this->getRequest()->getParams(), this works fine untill I introduce the checkboxset, now I am only able to retrieve the values of the checkboxes and no longer the values of all other fields.

It seems I can only have Fields or Checkboxset and not both together, doesn anyone have any idea what I may be doing wrong? I have pasted the code for my field-set below.

```
<fieldset name="invoice_details">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Supplier Payment</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    
    <checkboxset name="checkboxset_example">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="additionalInfo" xsi:type="string">Additional information</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Checkboxset Component Example</label>
            <options>
                <option name="0" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Option #1</item>
                </option>
                <option name="1" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Option #2</item>
                </option>
                <option name="2" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="number">3</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Option #3</item>
                </option>
            </options>
        </settings>
    </checkboxset>

    <field name="bank_reference">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Bank Reference</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">bank_reference</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">bank_reference</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="alpha-num" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

</fieldset>
```

Thanks,

Dan.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had not provided a dataScope attribute, this needs to be added to the config element of the checkboxset.

```
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">invoices</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Included Invoices</item>
            </item>
```